# Delete an unloaded workspace based on username or list all workspaces owned by user but unloaded

Tags: perforce

Being a perforce beginner, I have a very simple issue. I want to delete a work space but that has been unloaded from the disk. I don't remember the name of the work space else i would have reloaded and then deleted from the disk.

Is there a way to list all work spaces owned by a user which are unloaded and delete them or is there a way to list all work space owned by user but unloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `-U` flag to see unloaded workspaces.

Try `p4 clients -u the-user-name -U` to see that user's unloaded workspaces.